# Magento 2 shell shows production mode, but still in developer mode

Tags: magento2, developer-mode, production-mode

I have a problem turning the webshop into production mode. When I change mode to production all seems fine and production mode is enabled without any problem in ssh.

```
[admin@server public_html]$  php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
Maintenance mode already enabled
Starting compilation
Compilation was started.
%message% 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% ---------------------------]   0% ---------------------------]   0% -----------------------]  14% -----------------------]  14% -------------------]  28% 19 secs 184.0 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 2/7 [========>-------------------]  28% 19 secs 184.0 MiB
Service data attributes generation... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 19 secs 184.0 MiB
Application code generator... 3/7 [============>---------------]  42% 19 secs 184.0 MiB
Application code generator... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 33 secs 198.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 33 secs 198.0 MiB
Interceptors generation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 52 secs 270.0 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 5/7 [====================>-------]  71% 52 secs 270.0 MiB
Area configuration aggregation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 1 min 388.0 MiB
Interception cache generation... 6/7 [========================>---]  85% 1 min 388.0 MiB
Interception cache generation... 7/7 [============================] 100% 1 min 392.0 MiB
Generated code and dependency injection configuration successfully.
Compilation complete
Starting deployment of static content

Deploy using quick strategy
frontend/Magento/blank/sv_SE            2349/2349           ============================ 100% %  9 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/sv_SE         2771/2771           ============================ 100% %  8 secs
frontend/Magento/blank/en_GB            2349/2349           ============================ 100% %  9 secs
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US            2349/2349           ============================ 100% %  11 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB         2771/2771           ============================ 100% %  11 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US         2771/2771           ============================ 100% %  8 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/sv_SE             2365/2365           ============================ 100% %  11 secs
adminhtml/Meigee/Theme/sv_SE      2773/2773           ============================ 100% %  10 secs
frontend/Meigee/Theme/sv_SE       2386/2386           ============================ 100% %  9 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/en_GB             2365/2365           ============================ 100% %  13 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US             2365/2365           ============================ 100% %  11 secs
adminhtml/Meigee/Theme/en_GB      2773/2773           ============================ 100% %  11 secs
adminhtml/Meigee/Theme/en_US      2773/2773           ============================ 100% %  10 secs
frontend/Meigee/Theme/en_GB       2386/2386           ============================ 100% %  10 secs
frontend/Meigee/Theme/en_US       2386/2386           ============================ 100% %  12 secs

Execution time: 177.81827092171
Deployment of static content complete
Skipped disabling maintenance mode
Enabled production mode.
```

But, when going to Backend, and checking the js files etc I can see the shop is still in developer mode.

Months ago the shop was in Production mode, so I know it did work.

What can cause this issue?

- First I thought it can be I activated nginx ssl termination, with Varnish. And Redis. But I did go back to plain Apache without Varnish or Redis. Problem still exists
- I have checked .htaccess and the SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer is NOT set
- env.php shows 'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',

  1. How can I find the root to the problem? Where should I look?
  2. Can I somehow force the production mode?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check app/etc/env.php?

Comment: Yes, it looks good to me and is changing when I change mode:

    'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
    'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',

Comment: Very few visits here, I will try the Magento forum, must be more action. This part of Stackexchange seems dead.

Comment: How are you determaining that its still in developement mode?